ThingsBoard not displaying soil moisture data
Incredibly new to ThingsBoard and IoT, but I tried to make a soil moisture sensor a using Raspberry Pi Pico WH and a capacitive soil moisture sensor
This is the code I used to get the soil moisture data and send it to ThingsBoard (main.py):
from machine import ADC, Pin
import utime
import urequests #as requests
import network, time
from uthingsboard.client import TBDeviceMqttClient
import os
from ntpTime import ntpTime

soil = ADC(Pin(26)) #Soil moisture Pin reference


min_moisture = 30567
max_moisture = 46059

delayIoT = 360 #standard delay 360
delay_count = 0

#data connection
KEY = "******"
ssid = "********"
password = "*******"

#Configure Pico as Station
wlan=network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)

#create path
file_path = '/logs/log.txt'

timestrg = ""
timestrgthingsboard = ""

#function to read sensor data
def read_moisture():
    while True:
        moisture = round(max_moisture-soil.read_u16())*100/(max_moisture-min_moisture)
        print("moisture: " + "%.2f" % moisture +"% (adc: "+str(soil.read_u16())+")")
        utime.sleep(5) # set a delay between readings
        return moisture

def send_Thingsboard(moisture=""):
    client = TBDeviceMqttClient('thingsboard.cloud', access_token = KEY)
    client.connect()
    
    result = client.publish_data("v1/devices/me/telemetry", {"moisture":data},1)
    client.disconnect()

def write_log(date, message, value1="", value2="", value3="", value4=""):
    file = open(file_path, "a")
    file.write(date + '\t' + message + '\t' + value1 + '\t' + value2 + '\t' + value3 + '\t' + value4 + '\n')
    file.close()
    
def connect_wlan():
    current_time = utime.localtime()
    timestrg = "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % (current_time[0], current_time[1], current_time[2], current_time[3], current_time[4], current_time[5])
    max_wait = 60 * 15 #timer for connection
    wait = 0
    wait_count = 0
    
    if wlan.status() == 3:
        print('connected')
        write_log(timestrg, 'connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()
        print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )
        
    else:
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            wait = 5
            
            try:
                print("connecting to network...")
                write_log(timestrg, 'connecting')
                wlan.connect(ssid,password)
                utime.sleep(1)
                while wait >0:
                    if wlan.status() == 3:
                        break
                    wait -= 1
                    print('waiting for connection...')
                    write_log(timestrg, 'waiting for connection')
                    utime.sleep(1)
                    wait = 5
                    
                    while wait > 0:
                        if wlan.status() == 3:
                            break
                        wlan.disconnect()
                        utime.sleep(3)
                        wait -= 1
                        print('reconnecting...')
                        write_log(timestrg, 'reconnecting')
                        wlan.connect(ssid,password)
                        utime.sleep(1)
            except Exception as e:print(e.args)
        write_log(timestrg, e.args)
        wait_count += 11
        
        if wait_count >= max_wait:
            raise RuntimeError("network connection failed")
    write_log(timestrg, 'connection failed')
    
    try:
        tm = ntpTime.setTimeRTC()
        machine.RTC().datetime((tm[0], tm[1], tm[2], tm[6] + 1, tm[3], tm[4], tm[5], 0))
        print('date:', tm)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)
        write_log(timestrg, 'RTC' + e.args)
        pass 
         
#call wlan first time
connect_wlan()

#it works!
utime.sleep(1)


while True:
    moisture = read_moisture()
     
  current_time = utime.localtime()
  timestrg = "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d" % (current_time[0], current_time[1], current_time[2], current_time[3], current_time[4], current_time[5])
  

if delay_count >= delayIoT:
    try:
        if wlan.isconnected():
            print("sending...")
            send_Thingsboard(moisture)
            timestrgthingsboard = "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (current_time[3], current_time[4], current_time[5])
            write_log(timestrg, 'ThingsB', str(moisture), str(temp) + "C", str(pressure) + "hPa", str(humidity) + "%")
            print ('time for thingsboard: ', timestrgthingsboard)
            
        else:
            print("wlan not connected")
            write_log(timestrg, 'wlan not connected')
            connect_wlan()
            
    except Exception as e:
        print("except thrown (status =" + str(wlan.status())+")")
        print(e.args)
        write_log(timestrg, e.args)
        
    if wlan.status() != 3:
        print("trying to reconnect...")
        write_log(timestrg, 'trying to reconnect')
        connect_wlan()
        
    else:
        print("wlan connection is fine")
        delay_count = 0

This is a image of my dashboard
ThingsBoard Cloud Dashboard Image
.
When I ran the following code, it connected to WiFi just fine, but it did not send any data to my ThingsBoard Cloud dashboard and my device remains inactive.
I executed the curl command in my command prompt from the 'Check connectivity' button, but it only makes my device active temporarily and no data is sent either.
I also installed eclipse mosquitto but when I tried to execute this mosquitto_pub -d -q 1 -h "mqtt.thingsboard.cloud" -p "1883" -t "v1/devices/me/telemetry" -u "$ACCESS_TOKEN" -m {"temperature":25} in my command prompt, it shows this: 'mosquitto_pub' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'.
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.
